# Sources that are against אושפיזין custom?

Tags: minhag, sukkot, hachnasat-orchim-guests, ikarim

Are there any rabbinic sources that speak *against* the Sukkoth custom of inviting אושפיזין into the Sukkah? Or the formulation of its attendant text(s)?

I of course do not intend the righteous and proper practice of inviting living flesh and blood guests to share in our celebration of Sukkoth (see H. Y"T 6:18). Rather specifically the Zohar (3:103b) based practice of inviting seven of our physically deceased patriarchal ancestors into the Sukkah.

It would seem to me that this would be an area of discussion that potentially intersects with discussion of the prohibition of דורש אל המתים, angelic intercession, the Rambam's 5th iqqar, etc.

To be clear, I am seeking sourced answers - not independent speculation from contributors.

Thank you.

Comment: Do any of the texts include requesting or petitioning the guests? Or is it just announcing who's here? (I honestly don't know.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Admittedly, I have not examined many nushaoth of the text, however every version I have seen includes language directed to the אושפיזין, inviting them (אזמין לסעודתי אושפיזין עילאין) and directing/requesting them to sit/dwell (תיבו תיבו אושפיזין עילאין).

Comment: אזמין לסעודתי אושפיזין עילאין isn't directed at them (unless I'm misunderstanding the grammar)

Comment: How would you translate it? I would translate it as something along the lines of "I invite to my meal the exalted guests"

Comment: Yes, that's an announcement to the crowd, not a directive to anyone. It's declarative not imperative.

Comment: I mean, yeah, technically... but by analogy, if I declare in front of the amud: "I invite the holy ציבור to my sukkah for a qiddush" you don't think that my declaration would be conventionally interpreted as an imperative (i.e. "please, come to my sukkah!")? The same פשט applies here so far as I can tell...

Comment: The chabad minhag is to not use a specific text to invite them in but only to mention that they are present in the sukkah as an acknowledgement of them being guests.

Comment: @Dude yes, though this is in imitation of the third Lubavitcher Rebbe, who maintained that if one sees the אושפיזין then one need not verbalize an invitation (he reputedly had visions of them in his Sukkah). The last Lubavitcher Rebbe instructed that even though their custom is not to verbalize an invitation it ought nevertheless be extended mentally. There is a good summary of their practice [here](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F#.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.94.D7.92.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.9D).

Comment: @Deuteronomy it does not mean what you think it means. Here it's only saying you should think about them. This isn't the same as what you are implying

Comment: @Dude citing Hamelekh be'Mesibo vol. 2, p. 195 the author states: הרבי מסביר, שהמנהג להזמין את האושפזין בדיבור תמוה - כי הזמנת האושפיזין לא צריכה להעשות בדיבור ומספיק במחשבה, ומאידך, אם יזמין בדיבור ללא מחשבה וכוונה - דיבורו לא יועיל ואין בזה הזמנה כלל. If you have access to the work, please post a direct cite... otherwise this is all I've got to rely on as far as their practice is concerned.

Comment: [הזיות מאמיני האושפיזין](https://www.orharambam.com/post/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F)